# jsp page auto removes whitespaces

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, whitespace

I am writing lots of whitespaces as you can see the code below.

```
out.println("new Array('1453    12999   ALPER    KOPUZ')");
```

unfortunately when code compiles and run the code in the screen I am able to see it as

"1453 1299 ALPER KOPUZ".

It means it auto removes whitespaces and put only one whitespace after one word.It works fine at older versions of Internet Explorer  but it does show line such like "1453 1299 ALPER KOPUZ" at Internet explorer which I need to fix and our application runs on this server.

I tried css  "white-space: pre;" but it is still same.

This problem makes me crazy and ate my 3 hours. I would be glad if you have any idea to fix it.

Cheers 
Alper Kopuz

Comment: does this code compile?

Comment: Please add comments here in future, also can you please post your whole code I guess we are not on same page.

Answer (score -1):

I guess using out.println you are writing the text as HTML on your page as response.

You need to have the text pre formatted once you print it as HTML. Try to put your text in pre tag as shown below.

```
out.println("<pre>new Array('1453        12999 ALPER KOPUZ')</pre>");
```

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Can you please post what you have tried ? Also remove your answer and put comments below this. 

You are rendering your response as HTML right ?

Comment: Why downvote? Doesnt it is in the direction of what is asked ?

Comment: Shaikh your solution does not work. I wrote out.println("<pre>new Array('1453        12999 ALPER KOPUZ')</pre>"); such like you mentioned. Nothing show up when I applied your solution. You have more advices ?

Comment: Can you please post whole jsp code so that I can have a better idea of what you have tried otherwise i wilp get anoyher downvote for trying to solve your problem.

Comment: it is a very long code Shaikh :) It works on the previous versions of Internet Explorer. Code does not matter even when I paste code here(this page) it shows spaces per once after each word. It works same as I saw same from my page.  Posting whole code will not work out.println("<pre>new Array('1453        12999 ALPER KOPUZ')</pre>");  this is the code without spaces while I am posting, when I post the code you will see as below ( one whitespace after every word)

Comment: Can you please post the code in pastebin and share its link here ?